# Looking for a simple MEF code sample

Tags: mef

I'm looking for a simple code sample showing how to use Microsoft Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF).

I really like the code at http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2008/09/29/simple-introduction-to-composite-applications-with-the-managed-extensions-framework.aspx,  but it was written for MEF CTP 2 or 3 and the syntax has changed for the current version (CTP5).

Answer (score 2):

I would just download MEF and look at the included samples.

There is a page with [sample documentation](http://mef.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Samples) on the MEF site, as well.  The sample docs are a little out of date, though - the samples in the download are more current.  In addition, CTP5 added a new sample (MEF Studio).

In terms of looking at code, this is probably [the simplest sample](http://mef.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/30766#455150) to decipher.  The only part missing from that file is the definition on the MainWindow class:

```
[Export]
public partial class MainWindow
{
    // ...
```

If you add that, it's pretty much a complete sample.